# How long can a wire go?

Tags: terraria

I kind of want to make a huge gap between 2 teleporters from 1 side to the other, but I don't want to risk buying so many wires and then realize it can't go that far.

Is there a limit how far wires can go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not from what I experienced. I had the exact idea that you had, built it with friends and it worked perfectly. Just make sure not to leave any gaps (stupid advice but it's hard to keep track of the wire sometimes)

***EDIT:*** And according to the wiki, they removed the wire limit in patch 1.2.3
http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wire

Answer (score -2):

According to the Offical Terraria Wiki, wires can go up to 2,000 Blocks.

Comment: As the other answer says, and according to the [Official Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wire#History), they removed the length limit in patch 1.2.3. The 2,000 limit was only from 1.2 until then, and it was 1,000 before 1.2.